# Android App, how to run without GUI?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

How do I create a simple app that runs a method or activity without actually opening a gui?
I have the coding for the app already.
For example, a task manager on android I have has an icon that you push and it terminates apps running in the background without having to open an app and then pushing terminate manually.

Do I just remove the layout or do I need to have more than that?
Sorry for using the wrong terms, I'm still learning.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ran into your question by chance, I'm learning on the go myself. But it sound to me you maybe should consider making a service, and not an activity that has a layout. A service can work in the background and interact with other applications, which seems to me is your case.
[Android Service API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Good luck!